# Is there a better way to check if IDs are valid and present in a collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on the backend of a web application and I was wondering if there was a better way to make sure the IDs exist in the collection?

I'm already checking if the IDs are valid with the `router.param()` middleware but it doesn't tell me if they are present in the collection.

```js
module.exports.followUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.body.idToFollow))
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "ID unknown " + req.body.idToFollow });

  try {
    const followingUser = await UserModel.findById(req.params.id);
    const followedUser = await UserModel.findById(req.body.idToFollow);

    if (followedUser && followingUser) {
      UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        { $addToSet: { following: req.body.idToFollow } },
        { new: true }
      ).select("-password");

      UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.idToFollow },
        { $addToSet: { followers: req.params.id } },
        { new: true },
        (err, docs) => {
          if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
          else if (!docs)
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ message: "ID unknown " + req.params.id });
          else return res.status(200).json(docs);
        }
      );
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "One the IDs is not in the collection." });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to check if a document exists than using `.findById`. You can probably use `.exists` for a slight improvement over `findById`. `.exists` selects only _id and uses `.lean` so it's a bit faster. You can read more about it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.exists

Comment: Also you can call both find queries in parallel using `Promise.all` as they don't need to wait for each other to finish

Comment: (1) `UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(` - both the update methods require the `await`. (2) `ObjectId.isValid(` - is good. (3) When doing update's you don't do a `find` and then an `findOneAndUpdate`. You just do a `findOneAndUpdate`. You rely on the returned value to check if the update is successful or not - there is an option to get the updated values on a successful update. Having a separate read and update is also resource consuming.